# Where should I do the mapping? How can I do the mapping on repository? Datasource or Repository?

Tags: domain-driven-design, android-architecture

I'm implementing a clean architecture design: `ui -> domain <- data` **in modules (this is important)** and I've encountered a trouble.

I have the Repository and the DataSource. I create the ***repository and datasource*** interfaces in the **Domain module**

*DataSource:* Add functions that return data model in **Data module** (Entity, Remote)

*Repository:* Call datasource and do the mapping to domain objects.

Now I'm facing a problem. If I want to do the mapping on repository how can I do it without knowing the **data models**, **that seems impossible, in order to do the mapping on repository I need to know what kind of data models exists.**

**I don't want to do the mapping on DataSource since providing the raw data (data models) is its responsability**

What should I do here? What am I missing or not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Set repository interface in **domain module** and set DataSource interface in **data module**.

That way I'm able to do this mapping since implementations of Repository and DataSource are in data module. And now **DataSource** can return its **data models**